# How can I paint with canvas in a Scrollview?

Tags: android, canvas, scrollview

I have a canvas, in which I want to paint several rectangles, I can paint with canvas in an InternalView, but I need to paint in a scrollview, I tried with this code, but some have evil. 
This is the code:

```
   package prueba.android.ondraw;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Prueba_ondrawActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MyView v = new MyView(this);
        layout.addView(v);

    }
    private class MyView extends View{
        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            int j = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                super.onDraw(canvas);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                canvas.drawRect(0, j,50,50, paint);
                j= j+100;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Help please, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing some strange things in your code:
first you try to find a view (`findViewById()`) before you have used `setContentView()` (`sv` will always be null here, because there are no views yet), then you replace that View with a new ScrollView (which you don't use), and finally you set the content to a layout.

Instead what you probably *want* to do is create your own View, and then use that inside a ScrollView?

In your ScrollView, you have a layout, this will need an ID:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Then you find this layout in code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
//Create a new instance of MyView...
MyView v = new MyView(this);
//...And add it to the layout:
layout.addView(v);
```

And you can define your own `MyView` like this:

```
private class MyView extends View{
    //Your onDraw() method here.
}
```

(Notice that I call the custom View `MyView`. This is because android already have a class named `View`, so it could cause lots of confusion if you give classes names that already exist)

Comment: In this case, which is MyScrollView?

Comment: @user1369422 You would replace your `private class View extends ScrollView` with `private class MyScrollView extends ScrollView`, and also the constructor (`public View(Context context)` -> `public MyScrollView(Context context)`)

Comment: Now I can paint the rectangle, but I am not painting within the scrollview. Thank you for answering

Comment: @user1369422: Actually you are, but since the entire view is redrawn you won't really notice it is a ScrollView. I changed my answer a bit, try that instead.

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. Update current code again. To try it, I get the following error: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Comment: I see, you already have a view in your ScrollView. You would then replace the `ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) findViewById();`
to instead find the view inside the ScrollView and add your view to that. Note that the view inside the ScollView must be a ViewGroup (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout or similiar).

Comment: I have to replace that line by another line? Sorry, I don't understand clearly what I want to convey. Attached to the current code, the xml with the ScrollView

Comment: Thanks but i've Null Pointer Exception as line: layout.addView(v);

Comment: Don't forget the id for the LinearLayout, otherwise you won't find it, and `layout` will be null.

Comment: I have not forgotten, I'm back to update my code so that you can see

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. You must call `setContentView()` before `findViewById()`. setContentView() is what tells the activity where to get it's views. If you have not called it, there is no view to find for findViewById().

Comment: Thank you, there are no errors, but the rectangle does not get painted inside, or outside the scrollview, any idea?

Comment: My problem was that it gave no size to layout (layout.addView(v,300,300);
), thank you!